# ¿Cómo remover las primeras 10 palabras de un texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, map, txt, pop

Tengo un archivo *txt* con un poema de *Gibrán Halil Gibrán*, de donde debo eliminar las primeras 10 palabras, probablemente con un map y remove, pero no logro armarlo. Intenté esto con `pop()`.

```
for word in prophet:
    if word is [0]:
        prophet.pop[0]
    if word is [1]:
        prophet.pop[1]
        
print(prophet)
```

¿Cómo podría realizarlo?

Comment: `prophet = prophet[10:]` (suponiendo que `prophet` sea una lista y sus elementos cada palabra)

Comment: Si el texto es una larga cadena de palabras, prophet = " ".join(prophet.split()[10:]))

Comment: ¿palabras o letras? El título dice una cosa y el cuerpo de la pregunta, otra

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo sin necesita de bucles e If, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```py
with open("poema.txt","r") as file:
    lista_de_palabras = file.readline().split(" ")
    print(" ".join(lista_de_palabras[10:]))
```

Explico detalladamente lo que hace cada línea de código:

- Línea 1: Abres el Archivo «poema.txt» en modo lectura.
- Línea 2: Lees el contenido del archivo usando `readline()`, que naturalmente es un *String* y usando el método `split(" ")` divides su contenido al encontrar espacio y guardas el resultado en la Lista «lista_de_palabras».
- Línea 3: Ahora, deseas hacer dos cosas: eliminar las primeras 10 palabras y unificar nuevamente el poema sin estas 10 palabras. Para ello, en `lista_de_palabras[10:]` le estableces un Rango de índice lo que da como resultado una nueva Lista que empieza desde el rango especificado. Y, para unir nuevamente el poema se emplea el método `join()`, que permite unir los elementos de un iterable como en este caso una Lista, y como separador al unir las palabras usas el espacio en blanco. Finalmente imprimes el resultado en la Consola.

**poema.txt**

> La realidad de la otra persona no está en lo que te revela, sino en lo que no puede revelarte. Por lo tanto, si quieres entender a esa otra persona, no escuches lo que dice, sino lo que calla.

**Resultado:**

> que te revela, sino en lo que no puede revelarte. Por lo tanto, si quieres entender a esa otra persona, no escuches lo que dice, sino lo que calla.